# Input field not editable after I enabled the hide mobile input in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an input field in my android phone. When the 'hide mobile input' checkbox is disabled in the inspector, text is editable in the provided space but when enabled, the input field is no more editable. If I type multiple lines and found a mistake then I have to erase till that part and write again. Is there any way to make it editable without disabling the hide mobile input checkbox.

Comment: What is the motive behind you using the 'hide mobile input' checkbox?

Comment: I don;t want the provided fill space given by unity input field which is above the keyboard in phone. So I removed it by enabling the hide mobile input checkbox. But now it is uneditable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Hide mobile input' feature is applicable only for IOS

The additional input box works as preview of the text that user is typing so that the text is always visible for the user and not hidden by the on screen keyboard.

However, you can disable text preview by setting TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput property to true. Note that this works only for certain keyboard types and input modes. For example, it will not work on multi-line text input as in your case.

Have a look into this documentation 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-hideInput.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Deekshith, I am using Unity 2019.2.3f1, it is working for android. Maybe they have fixed it in the later version. The inbuilt feature of additional input box is editable and always visible to the user. But I removed it and added a script so that while typing in the text box, screen moves little up and becomes visible. The only thing I am unable to do is to make it editable.

Comment: You won't be able to make it editable by using 'hide mobile input' for android. As far as I know they haven't fixed this issue for mobile  input yet